# Jquery save input val to a label when button pressed

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Good morning everyone. I'm making a very long form using bootstrap, and jquery. I'm having problems with the last section where I should see a general review of the form which has been filled.
Here is a small example of the form

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

  var nomesalone = $('#nomeSaloneInput').val();
  $('#defNomeSalone').append(nomesalone);

  var indirizzo = $('#indirizzoInput').val();
  $('#defNomeSalone').append(indirizzo);

  var cap = $('#capInput').val();
  $('#defNomeSalone').append(cap);

  var citta = $('#cittaInput').val();
  $('#defNomeSalone').append(citta);

  var provincia = $('#provinciaInput').val();
  $('#defNomeSalone').append(provincia);

});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/daniele8808daniele8808/91nwfb83/) enter code here

What I'm trying to do is to save every input val inside the label at the bottom of the page, and every label should be saved when I click the OK button close to the input.
I tried several code. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle didn't have JQuery specified as a resource. Be careful with that when posting to SO. In addition, `append` will not rewrite the element. It will do exactly that: *append to it.*

Also, you were assigning this text to the same label element (`#defNomeSalone`) instead of different ones.

Change `append` to `text` and differentiate each label element when assigning text to it: http://jsfiddle.net/91nwfb83/15/

**Example:**

```
$('#defNomeSalone').text(nomesalone);
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited your fiddle, he's working now. 
JQuery import was missing.

Make sure you import jquery in your HTML template.

Answer (score 1):

use this.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var nomesalone = $('#nomeSaloneInput').val();
    var indirizzo = $('#indirizzoInput').val();
    var cap = $('#capInput').val();
    var citta = $('#cittaInput').val();
    var provincia = $('#provinciaInput').val();
    $('#defNomeSalone').text(nomesalone+' '+indirizzo+' '+cap+' '+citta+' '+provincia);
});
```